# AJAX Control Toolkit's combobox + IE are too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have problems with optimizing AJAX Control Toolkit. The specific problem is that **4800 records** take about **30 seconds** to bind in Internet Explorer (only **2 seconds** in Opera & Firefox). I've tried anything, but I still can't improve the load time in IE.

I've already enabled compression and caching, I'm using ToolkitScriptManager instead of ScriptManager. I've tried setting LoadScriptsBeforeUI and EnablePartialRendering to false, but it still doesn't help.

This is the query I use for binding.

```
var osoba =
     from o in db.osobas
     orderby o.osoba_prezime
     select new {
          o.osoba_id,
          person = o.osoba_prezime + " " +
                   o.osoba_ime + " | " +  
                   o.tijelo.tijelo_naziv + " | " +
                   o.radno_mjesto.rm_naziv_m
          };

cb1.DataSource = osoba;
cb1.DataTextField = "person";
cb1.DataValueField = "osoba_id";
cb1.DataBind();
cb1.Items.Insert(0, " ");
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 4,800 records in combo box is not a good design for any type of items, consider using another control or perhaps you can categorize and have filtering for the combo box

Comment: The problem is that I was asked to create a combobox that will be able to provide autocomplete. The main problem is why does it behave so badly in Internet Explorer while other browsers handle it well...

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have the developer toolbar open? I've had speed issues in IE when the toolbar is running, and when it's closed, load times are considerably faster.

Comment: No, I'm not using it, but thanks for the info anyway. It might be useful. ;)